# XCode Jenkins issue with Fastlane Build submit

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

In my Demo.xcworkspace, I am using fastlane with Jenkins
Here is the Shell command for in Jenkins

```
/usr/local/bin/fastlane beta
```

I am using fastfile for my Demo.xcworkspace project

```
default_platform(:ios)

fastlane_require 'dotenv'
before_all do
  # ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = "asdf-fdas-fxse-romk"
  Dotenv.overload '.env.beta'
end
platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  
  lane :beta do
      enable_automatic_code_signing
      increment_build_number
      gym(scheme: ENV["GYM_SCHEME"])
    upload_to_testflight(
      username: ENV("USERNAME"),
      app_identifier: ENV("DELIVER_APP_IDENTIFIER"),
      itc_provider: ENV("FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_ID"), # pass a specific value to the iTMSTransporter -itc_provider option
      skip_submission: true,
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )
  end
end
```

**Everytime I am able to generate ipa file but Build fails everytime with no specific errors.**